# Nested scrollbars on the Expander within the ListBox in WPF don't work

Tags: c#, wpf

The scrollbar from the opened Expander element inside the ListBox doesn't work and appears to have its own scrollbar, which isn't integrated into the parent's total height. When I click there, I can't scroll anymore. I just need one scrollbar regardless of the expand state and the amount of content present.

I tried googling, asking ChatGPT, Gemini, and couldn't find an answer. I also experimented with the structure in XAML and tried putting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" everywhere.

I know there are similar questions here, but I don't know how to apply them to my situation. Please don't burn me for asking a question.

Here is xaml code (tables and databases are string arrays):

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="False">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to replicate the TreeView control. You should use TreeView. It will behave as you would expect it to.